# Is "Good times take precedent over every incident" correct?

Tags: logic

1) Is it right sentence in terms of grammar? 2) Is it right sentence in terms of logic?

> **Good times take precedent** over every incident

[Link](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/beingasanocean/thehardestpartisforgettingthoseyousworeyouwouldneverforget.html) to lyrics

I think:

*Good times **to** take precedent*

OR

*Good times take precedent**s***

Comment: I believe the lyrics (though accurate, from what I can find) are grammatically incorrect - I think it should be 'precedence', not 'precedent'. http://www.dailywritingtips.com/precedent-vs-precedence/ gives more details.

Comment: They probably mean "take *precedence*" ... mistakes in the transcription of lyrics are pretty common.

Comment: I do not believe grammar is applicable to poetry or song writing :) Good grammar might limit the artist, isn't it?